# Accidentally used wrong git-restore command - are all my files gone?

Tags: git

I staged a wrong folder in my projected and wanted to remove that folder again from staging area. I accidentally used `git restore .` instead of `git restore --staged .` and all my unstaged (but tracked changes) were all removed. Is it possible to recover the files that was removed?

Comment: Not with Git: your work-tree is not stored in Git, it's just there for you to use (and to tell Git to overwrite, in this case). Do you have something like MacOS Time Machine with a backup from the time just before you did the `git restore`?

Comment: Are you developing in an IDE that may track history?